# How to separate the content of a button into another HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm working on an HTML file that acts as its own page in an Electron App. In this file, I have a button, which shows a pop-up form upon clicking. 
Here's the relevant code for the button and the content that pops up:

```html
<button class="open-button" id="openConfig">Change Configuration</button>

 <div class="modal-content" id="networkConfig">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h2>Configuration Settings</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
   <p>To get started, enter some initial information about the network you want to configure.</p>
   <p>Leave the number of nodes as zero if you would like to start from scratch.</p>
   <br />

   <p>Number of nodes:</p>
   <input type="number" id="nodeNumber" value="0" min="0" max="30">
   <br /><br />
   <p>Preference:</p>
   <div>
    <input type="radio" id="prefsecure" name="option" value="Secure" checked>
    <label for="prefsecure">Secure (Recommended)</label>
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="radio" id="prefefficient" name="option" value="Efficient">
    <label for="prefefficient">Efficient</label>
   </div>
   <br />

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="submit" class="btn">Start Configuration</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn cancel" id="closeConfig">Cancel</button>
   <br /><br />
  </div>
 </div>
```

Also, here are the relevant javascript functions that allow me to open/close this pop-up:

```html
function openForm() {
 document.getElementById("networkConfig").style.display = "block";
}
function closeForm() {
 document.getElementById("networkConfig").style.display = "none";
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.getElementById('openConfig')
  .addEventListener('click', openForm);
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.getElementById('closeConfig')
  .addEventListener('click', closeForm);
});
```

What I would like to do is take that content that pops up when the button is clicked (the button's id="openConfig") and put that into a separate HTML file (the id of the content I want in a separate file is "networkConfig"). This is to help compartmentalize my code. How can I make the button refer to this other file? Anyone has any leads? I would greatly appreciate any help at all!

Also, I apologize if I've made any mistake while posting this. It's my first post to stackoverflow, and I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for these past few days. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, the way for you to do that is to either POST the content you want to reuse somewhere, initializing an empty variable, adding the markdown and thus being able to prompt it elsewhere, or save a temporary file containing the markup (insecure).